# Which number is missing from the bottom grid?

Tags: mathematics

It's a hard puzzle, can you find the missing number?

[image: Can you find the missing number?]

Comment: Where is this puzzle from? It doesn't appear to be made by you and if that is the case you must endure you have permission to post it here and include the original source.

Answer (score 1):

I guess

> 56

Explanation:

> Pattern seems to be **left number** * 4/3 * **right number**

Comment: Thanks for answering the puzzle .
Your answer is correct , but can you find another way to solve it ?

Comment: Why do you need another way to solve it? Alex's answer seems reasonable; you say it's correct; it's short and simple. What more are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

> The answer is 55.9 means 56 
>  first box = 6*4 is 24 and 32/24 is 1.333333 
>  second box = 12*6 is 72 and 96/72 is 1.33333 
>  third box = 9*7 is 63 and 84/63 is 1.33333 
>  the missing puzzle contain 56 as 3*14 is 42 and 42*1.333333 is 56

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution:

> 428

because:

> if you concatenate the top numbers together (64, 126, 97), then subtract the bottom numbers from that, you get 32, 30, 14... See a pattern? The difference between these is 2, 16. Logically, the next one would be 128 (16*8), so the next difference would be 14-128, or -114. This makes the final (alternate) answer 314 + 114 = 428.

Comment: 97-84=13, but good effort

Comment: @JonMarkPerry whoops, I think I was a little too eager to find a pattern.